# Event for all activities

Tags: android, events, android-activity

Is there any way to throw an event in one class for all activities?

Actually I'm using custom listeners and registering them somewhere. But I would know if I can throw a customized event like "newMessageEvent" or similar and in every alive activity receive it.

I am using a good way or exists one better?

Does anybody knows?

Comment: Why would you need to throw a keyEvent on an Activity which is not active?

Comment: I don't say a KeyEvent, I say some event customized like "newMessageEvent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question done a long time ago to help if someone needs it one posible solution is:

1- Create a Singleton class that manages events like this:

```
    public class EventsManager {

    public enum EventType{
        //Define here your types
    }

    public interface EventsManagerListener{
        void onEvent(EventType eventType);
    }

    private static EventsManager instance;



    private  HashMap<EventType,List<EventsManagerListener>> listenersMap;

    private EventsManager(){
        listenersMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static EventsManager getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new EventsManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void registerForEvent(EventType eventType, EventsManagerListener listener ){
        List<EventsManagerListener> eventListeners = listenersMap.get(eventType);
        if(eventListeners == null){
            eventListeners = new ArrayList<>();
            listenersMap.put(eventType,eventListeners);
        }
        if(!eventListeners.contains(listener)) {
            eventListeners.add(listener);
        }
    }

    public void unregisterForEvent(EventType eventType, EventsManagerListener listener){
        List<EventsManagerListener> eventListeners = listenersMap.get(eventType);
        if(eventListeners != null){
            eventListeners.remove(listener);
        }
    }


    public void throwEvent(EventType eventType){
        List<EventsManagerListener> eventListeners = listenersMap.get(eventType);
        if(eventListeners != null){

            //This iteration sends the event to the newest activity first
            for(int i = eventListeners.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
                EventsManagerListener listener = eventListeners.get(i);
                listener.onEvent(eventType);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

2- Subclass Activity (for example MyBaseActivity)

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity{

}
```

3- Override onCreate and onDestroy methods and call the events manager and make the activity implement EventsManagerListener

```
    public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity implements EventsManagerListener{
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //...

            EventsManager.getInstance().registerForEvent(THE_EVENT_YOU_WANT, this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onDestroy(savedInstanceState);

            //...

            EventsManager.getInstance().unregisterForEvent(THE_EVENT_YOU_WANT, this);
        }

        public void onEvent(EventsManager.EventType eventType){
             //... handle the event
        }
```

}

4- Finally you have to call where you want to send that event the next line:

```
EventsManager.getInstance().throwEvent(YOUR_EVENT);
```

Hope that helps!